# Salvar array em diferentes colunas com fputcsv

Tags: php, pdo, aplicação-web, csv

Estou tentando fazer o output de alguns dados do BD para csv com o seguinte código:

```
while($linha=$buscar->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
   fputcsv($out, $linha);
}
   fclose( $out );
}
```

o que me retorna todo o conteúdo do array em uma só coluna. Como poderia fazer para que cada posição do array ficasse em uma coluna no csv?

**OBS:**

```
print_r($linha);
```

**resulta em :**

```
   Array
   (
     [data] => 20/05/2017
     [descricao] => pag 
     [pagamento] => 500
   )
```

Onde todos ficam na mesma coluna no csv, e no caso o ideal seria que cada um ficasse em uma coluna.

Comment: Poderia colocar o resultado de `print_r($linha);` na pergunta?

Comment: Desculpe, não entendi muito bem, devo colocar no código postado aqui?

Comment: Isso, edite a pergunta e coloca o resultado. Seu código parece correto só não entendi como tudo fica em um coluna só.

Comment: o código realmente está correto, ele faz o que eu pretendo, porém eu gostaria de um código a "mais" para organiza-lo por colunas, pois esse que apresentei cria uma linha por loop no csv, mas não cria uma coluna por array, que no caso é o que eu quero.

Comment: Adicione a solução do Problema como Resposta e não como edição da Pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problema resolvido com a adição de um ; no final do fput.

```
fputcsv($out, $linha, ';');
```